# How did Thanos know about the power of "The Snap"?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In the scene on Titan with Doctor Strange in *Avengers: Infinity War*, Thanos said,

> With all six Infinity Stones, I will simply snap my fingers and it would all cease to exist.

Then again, in the very first scene with Thor and Loki, when Maw gave Thanos the Space Stone, he said that no one has ever worn two Infinity Stones together.

So how come Thanos knew about the power of the Snap? Because as Wong puts it to Tony, the Big Bang hurled the six Infinity Stones across the universe.

So if no one had collected all the six stones before Thanos, then how did he know about the ability to "Snap"?

Comment: Worth pointing out that the snap was really just used to demonstrate it being simple to do anything when you have all the stones - Thanos could have clapped or just made a fist to achieve the same result.

Comment: He could have killed everyone from what I know, at least those not above him but he just wanted to kill half (randomly), he didn't need to snap his fingers, could have just used his mind really but as Dave pointed out it was made like for dramatic effect.

Comment: Hurled across the universe... and yet somehow half of them ended up on one insignificant little blue-green planet far out in the uncharted backwaters of the unfashionable end of the western spiral arm of the Galaxy.  Go figure.

Comment: @MasonWheeler I wonder why is that? I also wonder why he, being omnipotent, didn't double the resources instead of halving life forms?

Comment: People put way too much stock into "the snap". Snapping his fingers didn't actually do *anything* ... using the power of all the stones is what did something.

Comment: @ChatterOne That's actually covered in other questions - if you double the resources the population will grow dramatically to use them. If you halve the population it takes a lot longer to grow back up to 'dangerous' levels. Bigger question is why didn't he just change the laws of thermodynamics so that people wouldn't use up resources in the first place?

Comment: @Adonalsium That doesn't really matter, you're all powerful, you could make resources infinite. But in the end, it's just a typical action movie, no sense expecting a lot of depth. It was fun and that's about it :-)

Comment: @ChatterOne actually because resource density is what matters. If you make mars all of a sudden life sustaining and growing crops that won't solve hunger on Earth. To do that you'd have to actually grow the Earth's ability to grow crops. That would mean doubling the size and mass of the Earth. This would undoubtedly change gravity and the resulting jolt/quakes would cause far more damage to structures than having 50% of the planet randomly get dusted. It would probably kill that many people anyways.

Comment: Actually Thanos did mentioned that the resources in the Universe is finite.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck all true but still, if you're almighty you can fix all of that just by willpower. Of course you need to be smart. Maybe there's an intelligence stone somewhere... :-P

Comment: @ChatterOne the real reason is that Thanos...wasn't very smart. Also, he's a villain. And comes from a comic book. Comic book villains are notorious for being misguided. The movie did portray him as having logic for his actions but that doesn't mean his logic can't be *wrong*. The logic he presents is internally consistent which and he believes it to be true, but considered from an outsider it doesn't hold up very well. Which is *why* he's a villain, after all. Somebody doing the wrong thing for the right reasons is a tragic hero or similar.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Heck, most of them ended up in the same galaxy. I think Vormir is the only planet housing a stone not confirmed to be in the Milky Way.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It seems to be *general* knowledge that with the **all** the Infinity Stones the wielder (**if he is strong enough**) can do...

## Anything.

Certainly the Asgardians seemed to be aware of it...even Odin had a fake Gauntlet made up.

In addition, both Wong and Dr Strange are both aware of the Infinity Stones and their inherent nature and the power of individual stones is well documented across the previous MCU movies.

> Wong: [Using magic to show the universe and five out of six Infinity Stones] From the dawn of the universe, there was nothing. Then, boom! The Big Bang sent six elemental crystals, hurtling across the virgin universe. **These Infinity Stones each control an essential aspect of existence.**

...

> Tony Stark: [Speaking to himself] This is it....What's our timeline?
>
> Bruce Banner: No telling. He has the Power and Space Stones, that already makes him the strongest creature in the whole universe. If he gets his hands, on all six Stones, Tony...
>
> Doctor Strange: **He can destroy life on a scale hitherto undreamt of.**
>
> <sup>[Wikia Transcrip](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers:_Infinity_War)t</sup>

Comment: Also worth pointing out that there doesn't seem to be any gesture, ritual or other requirement for Thanos to use any of the individual stones when slotted in the gauntlet. He created portals with seemingly as much as a thought. So, we can guess that once all stones are combined, there really isn't any one thing Thanos needs to do in order to activate their combined power. A snap of a finger is dramatic but not the real trigger needed.

Comment: Actually, the rules of the MCU seem to require that he makes a fist to activate the Gauntlet but that's about it.

Comment: I thought I recalled him not doing that for few effects but then remembered that the heroes were really focused on keeping his palm open and that appeared to negate the powers. So I guess, a fist or some sort of similar gesture really was a requirement.

Comment: @vlaz, well yeah, the focus on the open-palm was so they could get the glove off. (Given Thanos' personality, I'd guess he just liked to clench his fists a lot, not that it was a requirement for objects of vast cosmic power.)

Comment: @ThunderGuppy But, as soon as he had his hand free, he closed his fist and started using the power of the Infinity Stones to attack the Avengers et al - if he didn't need to close his fist, why didn't he just Reality Stone them into ribbons?

Comment: Maybe some finger have to be in contact with the palm in order to "clause the circuit".

Comment: @DragandDrop completely conjecture, but certainly a reasonable precaution for something that powerful. It might not even be an actual limitation, the connection may simply help Thanos visualize his intent to use a particular combination of stones.

Comment: @Chronocidal - This was discussed in the maker's commentary. They needed Thanos to have some element of control that was external *in order to allow the Avengers to fight him* ("Don't let him close his fist")

Answer (score 31):

There is no power in the snap. That is just a gesture that - for all we know - Thanos himself picked arbitrarily.

This is all based on folklore. Magic and superpowers quite often have some kind of activation gesture, command word or other specific "on" switch. Which makes sense as you don't want to turn them on or off randomly. So there needs to be **something** that tells the Infinity Stones "ok, NOW" - and for Thanos, that was a snap of his fingers.

In a movie (or comic), of course, this is doubly true. You need some kind of visual gesture for the watcher/reader. While activating a power by thought alone might work for powers that are themselves visual, this specific one isn't, so you need a visual activation gesture. The "snap of a finger" is well-picked for that as it shows that the true power is in the stones, not the gesture. If it had been some kind of elaborate ritual, it would have had less impact in demonstrating just how powerful the stones are. Fingersnapping is considered a "mimimal" gesture in our culture, so using it to power the opposite - the maximal effect - is quite effective in a story-telling way.

Comment: Just to further this "with a snap of my fingers" is not exactly a *spoken* idiom but still often used to describe something extremely easy. For example, you can say "I can win the ice cream hotdog eating contest like *that*" and snap your fingers timed with the emphasis on the last word. Meaning, it's easy. Occasionally you can also express the action verbally to similarly show how easy it is - like Thanos and other characters did by describing something happening with a snap of fingers (rather than mimicking the action).

Comment: What amazes me is that he can snap his fingers while wearing a metal gauntlet that covers his fingertips.

Comment: @vlaz what do you mean? It is absolutely an idiom and quite a common one. See [1](https://www.yourdictionary.com/snap-of-a-finger), [2](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/snap+fingers), [3](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snap_of_a_finger). . .

Comment: @MarkTO Did he?  I'd have to go back and rewatch, but I thought he snapped with his other (un-gauntleted) hand.

Comment: @MarkTO He had all the infinity stones, he can do whatever he wants.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, with the gauntlet he snaps. But its a common miss conception as a lot of  of picture show him snaping with the ungauntleted hands

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, with the gauntlet he snaps. But its a common miss conception as a lot of of picture show him snaping with the ungauntleted hands, https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2Mbm.png

Comment: That's a different scene.  There's one scene where he tells people his plan and that he's going to snap his fingers, which is what's shown there, but when he actually does the deed, he's by himself - does he use the same hand both times?

Comment: @MarkTO Reality Stone let's him cheat. His snap can sound like whatever he wants it to sound like.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman No, that's definitely the scene where he actually does it. Thor hits him in the chest with Stormbreaker, then Thanos says he should have aimed for the head and does the Snap.

Comment: What's weird is that he does seem to need to close his fist to use most powers of the gauntlet, as we can see in the battle on Titan (Infinity Wars) and the last battle of Endgame. So gesture or no gesture ?