# Does the wielder of the Gauntlet actually need to snap, or is the snap action simply dramatic?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, is the snap simply dramatic, or does the wielder of the Gauntlet needs to follow this ritual to actually activate it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How did Thanos know about the power of "The Snap"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96653/how-did-thanos-know-about-the-power-of-the-snap) - questions and answers elaborate on why one would snap instead of, say, clap hands or tap dance (basically, yes, the snap is for dramatic effect. You need something to tell the power to activate, but that can be anything - after all, you can do anything you want with these pebbles)

Comment: AFAIK, it's dramatic. finger snap usually symbolizes very easy and quick thing that a person can do. so Thanos' snap shows how powerful the stones are and how powerful he weilder can get

Comment: @Jenayah I would so much like to see Thanos tap dance please

Comment: But keeping Thanos' hand open somehow keeps him from using the power of the gauntlet, both in "Infinity War" and "Endgame".

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate....yes, one of the answers given to the other question also answers this question; but the question being asked is completely different, and the accepted answer to that question doesn't address this one at all.

Answer (score 8):

It's a figurative action.

I recall Thanos saying well before he obtained the gauntlet that he just wanted to solve the problems of the universe with a snap of his fingers.

Other power-related actions didn't require a finger snap, only dramatic gestures - and even those probably aren't strictly needed.

Comment: This is what I thought. But in Endgame, Carol appears to be able to prevent Thanos from using the gauntlet by literally keeping his fingers apart.

Comment: She was trying to remove it, Thanos was trying to keep it.  The fight over this was enough to distract him away from snapping.

Comment: @Raj They also established in Infinity Wars that if Thanos was unable to close his fist he wasn't able to utilize the power of the glove. She is holding his hands apart for that reason as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple times throughout Infinity War that Thanos used the power of the gauntlet without snapping his fingers; sometimes he just points the respective stone at the object he's controlling and sometimes he just closes his hand. The fact that he decided to snap his fingers to use all of the stones is a formality that he imposed himself.